# To whom should I return my trophies

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Witcher 3, the trophies description says that it can be returned for a reward but I am not sure who to return those trophies to.

Answer (score 23):

Note: This vendor was patched in version 1.12 (released in January 2016). The alchemist no longer buys at 100% of cost. Leaving the answer up as it might be relevant to GoG purchasers who haven't patched.

The alchemist near Oxenfurt Gate (north east of Novigrad) will buy trophies from you, for a better price. He also sells extremely reasonably priced precious stone dust (and other alchemical ingredients).

[image: Map Image]

He turns up at around 5am (you'll need to be outside of the building, otherwise he won't spawn).

He'll actually buy anything for it's full price, though he has a limited amount of Crowns.

Comment: That guy said "If anyone asks, you have not seen me" :-)

Answer (score 1):

After killing the beast you usually return to the one that gave you the mission to collect your reward but you don't hand back the trophy to him/her, you just keep it yourself. You can then sell it or equip to buff some stat.