# Do different vendors have different sell prices?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I don't have a good read on whether I'm better holding off to find a smith to sell my vendor trash weapons or whether any merchant will do. Sometimes it seems like payouts are better when it's to the appropriate vendor (books to a book seller, etc.), but I haven't been able to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct: different, type-specific vendors offer better prices for their type of item.

More details can be found in my answer, [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/221854/16979).